# I am creating a dict from a file with duplicate values. How do I prevent my loop overwriting existing values?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, text

I'm having a real headache with a python script.

It basically loads a DNS zone like txt file that looks like this:

```
name.com 3600 MX ns1.google.com
name1    3600 A  1.2.3.4
```

I am loading this file into python, looping through each line and converting each line to a list, so the above data would look like this:

```
[["name.com", "3600", "MX", "ns1.google.com"],["name1","3600","A","1.2.3.4"]] etc
```

I then need to take each list and assign bits of data to a dict like so:

```
for each_list in data:
     terrarecord[each_list[0].replace('.', '') + str(self.random)] = {
                "zone_id": self.zone_id,
                "name": each_list[0] + self.url, 
                "type": each_list[2],
                "ttl": each_list[1],
                "records": [each_list[3].replace('\n', '')]
            }
```

which for the above example text file is all fine and dandy. However if I have a zone file with duplicate entries such as below, this loop is writing over them causing all sorts of havoc.

```
name.com 3600 MX ns1.google.com
name1    3600 A  1.2.3.4
name1    2000 A  1.2.2.2 # <--- this will overwritten
```

How can I write this loop so it creates a new dict object each time instead of writing over an existing dictionary?

Comment: Do you have to use a dictionary? Could you tell me what you use `terrarecord` for, like what code segment uses it? It makes sense why the overwrite is takeing place, dictionaries by definition need to have unique keys. So the last assignment to a particular key would overwrite the previous values.

Comment: It's to create a terraform file, so it has to be in json format

Comment: You need to create a unique, hashable, key that could be based on the name, but maybe other factors as well. This is one way to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing that comes to mind would be to use a `defualtdict` with a `list`. Like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict
...
terrarecord = defaultdict(list)
...
terrarecord[each_list[0].replace('.', '') + str(self.random)].append({
            "zone_id": self.zone_id,
            "name": each_list[0] + self.url, 
            "type": each_list[2],
            "ttl": each_list[1],
            "records": [each_list[3].replace('\n', '')]
        })
```

The result will be that each key will be associated with a list of values, in the same order as they were entered. If you need a regular dict specifically, you can always convert it back like so:

```
terrarecord = dict(terrarecord)
```